# Coldfusion, IIS PCI Scan ServletExec vunerability?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, pci-compliance

I have a 64bit server with the Coldfusion 9.0.2 with IIS, our latest server scan for PCI compliance returned the following error as "urgent"

**Unify eWave ServletExec 3.0C UploadServlet Unprivileged File Upload**

- Is this part of Coldfusion? or IIs.
- is it safe to remove it?
- how do i remove it?

Comment: This thread seems useful: http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-server/thread.cfm/threadid:1195

Comment: And this: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/prevent-coldfusion-mx-answering-servlet.html